# change characters of the alphabet to * just for the password

Tags: python

I need help to change the letters of the alphabet and numbers (from 0-9) another character like * so that when I type the password people can't look over my shoulder and find out the password. can anyone help?

Comment: We need some more context here. Is this when you're using the `input()` function or something? Details!

Answer (score 4):

If your primary concern is simply hiding your password from other people, you should use the built-in [`getpass.getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) function:

```
>>> from getpass import getpass
>>> getpass()
Password:
'abc123'
>>>
```

As a bonus, `getpass` keeps the length of the password concealed (people can easily count the `*`'s).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `getpass` module to hide the password when typed

```
>>> import getpass
>>> passwd = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")
Enter password:
>>> print passwd
thisismypassword
>>>
```

Comment: does this work in python 2.7

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар yes it does